# Removing hidden files recursively of a certain prefix in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am moving files from my Mac to my Windows 10 PC and have unfortunately carried over a massive number of duplicate files prefixed with `._`.  I am not a Windows user.  How can I recursively remove all of these files in Windows?

Comment: How would you have done it on the Mac? Being able to answer that would generally be a good place to start, as there are sites out there that can tell you the Windows equivalent to a Mac operation - provided you can identify the Mac operation you want the equivalent for.

Comment: I would have opened a terminal and done `find . -name '._*' -delete` or `find . -name '._*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: You could use PowerShell (`Get-ChildItem`, `Remove-Item`) for this. It works much like what you would do on Linux. In PowerShell you can either use `Get-Help <cmd>` or `<cmd> -?` to get some more information.

Comment: OK, since you're clearly not afraid to use a scriptable shell, I'd recommend using PowerShell. You'll want the [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) and [`Remove-Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) cmdlets to do this; you should also look at [Understanding the Windows Powershell Pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/understanding-the-windows-powershell-pipeline).

Comment: Ok, I'm not in front of my box right now but I'll look into this PowerShell thing :).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at PowerShell and instead of trying to learn a whole new feature set I discovered Windows 10 has integrated Ubuntu and bash!  Reading this article  [How To Geek - Windows 10 Bash shell](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) - was a great walk through on how to enable it through developer mode.  After enabling it I was able to use all my standard Linux commands to do what I needed to.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  For other users who encounter a similar problem, it would be helpful if you could expand the answer to include your actual solution.